# express.json and bodyparser.json not delivering large payload of base64 image

Tags: express, heroku

Over the last day I have tried all solutions on the web related to express.json and bodyparser.json. (my app is on heroku) I have the following post request for a large 13mb image:

```
const myAddJSON3 = JSON.stringify({ email: 'yonikirby@gmail.com',
date: Date.now(), relation: "cousin",
 tips: "אחרי שהישיבה על הסכם השכר בין הסתדרות המורים לאנשי האוצר אמש התפוצצה, הודיעה יפה בן דויד על החרפת הצעדים: ",
location: "Brazil",
fileBase64: fs.readFileSync('purpleflowers.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'}),
memoryowner: "Yoni Kirby"
});
    
  const addMemory = async() => { 
    try {
    await axios.post('https://calm-stream-62617.herokuapp.com/api/memories/saveOneMemory', myAddJSON3, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      } 
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("axios saveonememory success: " + JSON.stringify(response.data) );
   
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log("axios add memory fail: " + error.response.data.message);
   
    }
  });
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);    
}
}
 
addMemory();
```

On the server side I have the following:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//app.use(express.json({limit:'50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true, type:'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000, type:'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.text({ limit: '50mb', type:'application/json' }));


module.exports = app => {
    
    const controller = require("../controllers/controller.js");
    var router = require("express").Router();                    
    router.post("/saveOneMemory", controller.saveOneMemory);
```

I have tried every fix on the internet related to express.json and bodyparser.json, but it doesn't process a large base64 string coming through, just a very small one. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly happens when you upload the large version? Do you get a specific HTTP status back? Are you sure Heroku doesn't impose a limit?

Comment: I read and heroku has a 300mb or so limit. And nothing at all happens when I upload the large version.

Comment: a friend said she gets a 413 payload too large however

Comment: If nothing happens at all, that's strange in and of itself. The 413 seems to suggest that `body-parser` is limiting the request body. Can you show more on how your app is configured in terms of middleware and routing?

Comment: module.exports = app => {
    console.log("in routes.js")
    const controller = require("../controllers/controller.js");
    var router = require("express").Router();                    
    router.post("/saveOneMemory", controller.saveOneMemory);

Comment: Please add it to your question :) Also include how/where you configure `body-parser`

Comment: How is `router` attached to `app`? Where _exactly_ is the `body-parser` added to app? With Express, middleware and route setup is very order-dependent, and you're not showing in which order your app it setting them up. Also, have you tried running your code locally to rule out the issue is with Heroku?

Comment: app is defined, then body parser is added, then the router is added. I have not run it locally but I should try now

Comment: It doesn't seem to work locally, unfortunately

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with a simple [example](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/8adbfe085c2f120083b7392b2297b4bf), it accepts an 18MB JSON file just fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for trying that! It must be Heroku then

Comment: But you said it doesn't work locally either?

Comment: No, it didn't work locally, but it did for you, and that's what matters. It didn't even work locally for the image with the small size

Comment: Well, my _own_ example worked for me. I can't test your code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was Heroku, not bodyparser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).